# Find OpenVPN IP based on client's public key/cert

Tags: openvpn

A client is connected to an OpenVPN network. I'm on the OpenVPN server and have access to the client's public key/cert file (e.g. *client5.crt*).

(How) can I find out what IP is assigned to the client in the OpenVPN network based on that?

Comment: How is the client obtaining an IP address?  Is it statically assigned or assigned by a DHCP server?

Comment: @heavyd For some clients, it's assigned statically. For others, it's not (so I assume a DHCP server?) I'd love a solution which would work in both those cases, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that one should be able somehow to extract a *"Common Name"* from a public key/cert (TODO: how?).
2. Then, one can enable "management console" in the OpenVPN server (line `management /var/run/openvpn.mgmt unix` in openvpn config), and [query it](https://superuser.com/a/727203/12184) to match *"Common Name"* with an IP:

   ```
   $ echo 'status 2' | socat stdio /var/run/openvpn.mgmt | grep '^ROUTING_TABLE' | cut -d, -f2-3
   10.91.0.1,foobar
   10.91.0.6,other-name
   ...
   ```

Something based on this may work, as long as every client has a unique *"Common Name"*.